# error inflating class and memory issues

Tags: android, class, memory

I have an app that has 2 main layouts and does use alot of pictures (16). The app works fine but it seems after going between layouts a few times it crashes and I believe it is because it is running out of memory. Im not sure how to fix this besides making the pictures smaller.. any suggestions?

```
06-14 14:28:10.543584-616/? E/NotificationService: Ignoring notification with icon==0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=nullnull defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null])
06-14 14:28:15.678  19572-19572/?E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 2764816-byte allocation.
06-14 14:28:15.698  19572-19572/?E/dalvikvm: Extra info: Footprint=63559KB, Allowed Footprint=65543KB, Trimmed=7916KB
06-14 14:28:15.718  19572-19572/?E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.simplequiz.plus/com.nick.simplequiz.plus.saveImage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #403: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #403: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:363)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
        at com.nick.simplequiz.plus.saveImage.onCreate(saveImage.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
        ... 26 more
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=65543KB, Allocated=57586KB)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:626)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1959)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
        ... 29 more
06-14 14:28:15.728  584-595/?E/EmbeddedLogger: App crashed! Process: com.nick.simplequiz.plus
06-14 14:28:15.728  584-595/?E/EmbeddedLogger: App crashed! Package: com.nick.simplequiz.plus v6 (1.0)
06-14 14:28:15.728  584-595/?E/EmbeddedLogger: Application Label: Name the plane plus!
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue before. I believe the 
issue is due to recreating the bitmap every time 
you start the activity.  Here's a snippet of what 
i did to get rid of the issue.

```
    Bitmap d;
    private void setImage(String path){
    if(d != null){
        d.recycle();
    }
    d = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


    if(d != null){
        profilePicture.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(d));
        }       
    }
```

Comment: ok i am a bit confused. i am using png images in image views, so should i recycle them when my activity is destroyed or paused?

Comment: Ah I see. So the images are coming from drawable resources? If you can find a way to save the images after they're created then you can recycle them. I think the issue is coming from re-creating the images.  I'm not quite sure how to do this though.

Comment: Yes all of the images are from drawable resources. I am new to android/java programming and I am not entirely sure of the difference between a bitmap and a jpeg image. Is it more preferred to use bitmap images or jpeg images or does it not matter?